# How to mock method calls of mock objects?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, jmock

Consider this example

```
    resp.getWriter().write(Collections.singletonMap("path", file.getAbsolutePath()).toString());
```

where `resp` is `HttpServletResponse` and is mocked.

I am using `JMock` [Mockery](http://www.jmock.org/cheat-sheet.html) to mock these

My code looks like

```
   try {
          atLeast(1).of(resp).getWriter().write(String.valueOf(any(String.class)));
        } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
        will(returnValue("Hello"));
```

When I run this, I get

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Which I believe is coming since `getWriter()` is not sending anything back

How do I handle this situation?

Comment: simply your getWriter() of the mock should return a mock of writer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need 2 mock objects.

```
HttpServletResponse resp = context.mock(HttpServletResponse.class);
Writer writer = context.mock(Writer.class);
```

...

```
atLeast(1).of(resp).getWriter();
will(returnValue(writer));
allowing(writer).write(with(any(String.class));
```

Answer (score 1):

I would not use a mock for `Writer`. You want to test that the output gets written, not the interaction that causes the output to get written.

Instead, use a real object:

```
HttpServletResponse mockResponse
    = context.mock(HttpServletResponse.class);
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
```

...

```
atLeast(1).of(mockResponse).getWriter();
will(returnValue(writer));
```